# Request with multipart/form-data returns 415 error

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc

I need to receive this request using `Spring`:

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1
user-agent: Dart/2.8 (dart:io)
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--dio-boundary-3791459749
accept-encoding: gzip
content-length: 151
host: 192.168.0.107:8443

----dio-boundary-3791459749
content-disposition: form-data; name="MyModel"

{"testString":"hello world"}
----dio-boundary-3791459749--
```

But unfortunately this `Spring` endpoint:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public void test(@Valid @RequestPart(value = "MyModel") MyModel myModel) {
    String testString = myModel.getTestString();
}
```

returns `415` error:

```
Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--dio-boundary-2534440849' not supported
```

to the client.

And this(same endpoint but with the `consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE`):

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void test(@Valid @RequestPart(value = "MyModel") MyModel myModel) {
    String testString = myModel.getTestString();
}
```

again returns `415` but, with this message:

```
Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported
```

I already successfully used this endpoint(even without `consumes`) with this old request:

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=62b81b81-05b1-4287-971b-c32ffa990559
Content-Length: 275
Host: 192.168.0.107:8443
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/3.8.0

--62b81b81-05b1-4287-971b-c32ffa990559
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MyModel"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 35

{"testString":"hello world"}
--62b81b81-05b1-4287-971b-c32ffa990559--
```

But unfortunately now I need to use the first described request and I can't add additional fields to it.

So, I need to change the `Spring` endpoint, but how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to have your controller method consume `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE`,

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
......
```

You also need to add a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` support `application/octet-stream`. In this answer,

- I configure it by using `WebMvcConfigurer#extendMessageConverters` so that I can keep the default configuration of the other converters.(Spring MVC is configured with Spring Boot’s converters).
- I create the converter from the `ObjectMapper` instance used by Spring.

[For more information]
[Spring Boot Reference Documentation - Spring MVC Auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration)
[How do I obtain the Jackson ObjectMapper in use by Spring 4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060006/how-do-i-obtain-the-jackson-objectmapper-in-use-by-spring-4-1)
[Why does Spring Boot change the format of a JSON response even when a custom converter which never handles JSON is configured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462767/why-does-spring-boot-change-the-format-of-a-json-response-even-when-a-custom-con)

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        ReadOnlyMultipartFormDataEndpointConverter converter = new ReadOnlyMultipartFormDataEndpointConverter(
                objectMapper);
        List<MediaType> supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        supportedMediaTypes.addAll(converter.getSupportedMediaTypes());
        supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);

        converters.add(converter);
    }

}
```

[NOTE]
Also you can modify the behavior of your converter by extending it.
In this answer, I extends `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` so that

- it reads data only when the mapped controller method consumes just `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE`
- it doesn't write any response(another converter do that).

```
public class ReadOnlyMultipartFormDataEndpointConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {

    public ReadOnlyMultipartFormDataEndpointConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        super(objectMapper);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Type type, Class<?> contextClass, MediaType mediaType) {
        // When a rest client(e.g. RestTemplate#getForObject) reads a request, 'RequestAttributes' can be null.
        RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        if (requestAttributes == null) {
            return false;
        }
        HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) requestAttributes
                .getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_HANDLER_ATTRIBUTE, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
        if (handlerMethod == null) {
            return false;
        }
        RequestMapping requestMapping = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
        if (requestMapping == null) {
            return false;
        }
        // This converter reads data only when the mapped controller method consumes just 'MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE'.
        if (requestMapping.consumes().length != 1
                || !MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE.equals(requestMapping.consumes()[0])) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.canRead(type, contextClass, mediaType);
    }

//      If you want to decide whether this converter can reads data depending on end point classes (i.e. classes with '@RestController'/'@Controller'),
//      you have to compare 'contextClass' to the type(s) of your end point class(es).
//      Use this 'canRead' method instead.
//      @Override
//      public boolean canRead(Type type, Class<?> contextClass, MediaType mediaType) {
//          return YourEndpointController.class == contextClass && super.canRead(type, contextClass, mediaType);
//      }

    @Override
    protected boolean canWrite(MediaType mediaType) {
        // This converter is only be used for requests.
        return false;
    }
}
```

**The causes of `415` errors**

When your controller method consumes `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE`, it doesn't handle a request with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;`. Therefore you get `415`.

On the other hand, when your controller method consumes `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE`, it can handle a request with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;`. However JSON without `Content-Type` is not handled depending on your configuration. 
When you annotate a method argument with `@RequestPart` annotation,

- `RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver` parses a request.
- `RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver` recognizes content-type as `application/octet-stream` when it is not specified.
- `RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver` uses a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to parse a reuqest body and get JSON.
- By default configuration `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` supports application/json and application/*+json only.
- (As far as I read your question) Your `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`s don't seem to support `application/octet-stream`.(Therefore you get `415`.)

**Conclusion**

Therefore I think you can successfully handle a request by letting `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`(an implementation of `HttpMessageConverter`) to support `application/octet-stream` like above.



**[UPDATE 1]**

If you don't need to validate `MyModel` with `@Valid` annotation and simply want to convert the JSON body to `MyModel`, `@RequestParam` can be useful.
If you choose this solution, you do **NOT** have to configure `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to support `application/octet-stream`.
You can handle not only JSON data but also file data using this solution.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void test(@RequestParam(value = "MyModel") Part part) throws IOException {

    // 'part' is an instance of 'javax.servlet.http.Part'.
    // According to javadoc of 'javax.servlet.http.Part',
    // 'The part may represent either an uploaded file or form data'

    try (InputStream is = part.getInputStream()) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyModel myModel = objectMapper.readValue(part.getInputStream(), MyModel.class);

        .....
    }
    .....
}
```

**See Also**

[Javadoc of RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.html)
[Javadoc of MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html)
[Content type blank is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207486/content-type-blank-is-not-supported/60213085#60213085) (Related question)
[Spring Web MVC - Multipart](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-multipart-forms)

Comment: Thanks, it's works. But now I have a different problem: now my other endpoints(even without `multipart`) sometimes respond not in the correct format. How can I specify that this `bean` should only be used in the endpoint with the `consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE` and only for the requests, not for the responses?

Comment: I added ‘UPDATE 1’ to my answer. This is just a quick note to tell you a possible solution. This solution has some limitation (e.g. you can’t do validation with `@Valid` ) so I am still thinking about whether we have better solutions.

Comment: I will need to send files(e.g. images) to the server, so I'm not sure about this solution. I think I need to use part.

Comment: I edited the code snippet of 'UPDATE 1' so that we can use 'javax.servlet.http.Part'(and I am still thinking about whether we have better solutions). You can handle file data using `javax.servlet.http.Part`.

Comment: I added the custom converter code snippet. I am still a bit confused about your use case. Do you wish to read both JSON data and file data by the same controller method(e.g. both JSON data and file data read into the same argument of `test` method)? Or do you wish to have some end points read JSON data only and some other end points read file data only?

Comment: [1/2] Sorry for the long delay - I thought that I can fix the problem on the client, but unfortunately it didn’t work out. 
Let's discuss the solution with the converter.
I'm still facing the problem with the wrong response of the other endpoints, e.g. my endpoints returns Date in milliseconds, but before it was in the String. It's not the problem, but it shows that this convertor impacts other endpoints.

Comment: [2/2] I added two files: MultipartConfigurer and ReadOnlyMultipartFormDataEndpointConverter, and changed `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to `ReadOnlyMultipartFormDataEndpointConverter` in the `MultipartConfigurer`, but still have the same problem with the dates(or even maybe with something else that I have not yet noticed). About your question: I want to read both file and JSON in the same method, e.g. for registration - user sends account information and avatar in the same time.

Comment: I found out that the cause of the wrong response (Date in milliseconds format) is not a behavior of ReadOnlyMultipartFormDataEndpointConverter. When we configure the converter with `HttpMessageConverters`, It affects the configuration of other converters. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462767/why-does-spring-boot-change-the-format-of-a-json-response-even-when-a-custom-con) I edited the configuration in my answer so that we can avoid it. Also I changed the way obtaining the `ObjectMapper` instance so that the custom converter is created with the instance used in Spring.

Comment: Many thanks for so much efforts! I really appreciate this!

Comment: I placed the two classes into a folder under main named 'config', but the problem remains.  Getting a 415 error along with an error saying CORS is violated (whcih seems strange as CrossOrigin is set)

Comment: @jojeyh I think this is another kind of problem. I recommend you to post a new question.

Comment: This is the only solution i found for my use case +1